# Passar parâmetro para rota no javascript em laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

Boa tarde, tenho uma dúvida sobre parâmetros em `laravel` que não achei no site, tenho uma rota como esta:

```
Route::get('busca/{id}', 'MatriculasController@busca');
```

que passa um parâmetro para um método no `controller` do `laravel`.

> Minha dúvida é no `javascript` como coloco o parâmetro na rota?

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar nessa dúvida por favor?

Comment: Depende, pois terá que enviar uma requisição via ajax para ter o retorno do json.

Há três formas nativas de se trabalhar com o javascript no laravel "dependendo da versão", são eles  javascript puro "vanilla js", jquery e vue.js

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver, segue o código caso alguém esteja com esse mesmo problema:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        fetch_customer_data();

     function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
     {
      $.ajax({
       url:"{{ route('live_search.action') }}",
       method:'GET',
       data:{query:query},
       dataType:'json',
       success:function(data)
       {
        $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
        $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
       }
      });
     }

     $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
      var query = $(this).val();
      fetch_customer_data(query);
     });
     });
```

No controller simplesmente chama assim:

```
$query = $request->get('query');
```

Resumindo no parâmetro data do ajax/jquery se define o parametro do método no controller. abç.